# Most Efficient Way of Reading Serial Data for a Fix Amount of Time

Tags: c#, serial-port

I wanna keep reading data from my serial for a fix amount of time. My code, which was taken from a couple different ideas, is working. However, I would like to double-check if this is the correct and best way. My code at this point is:

```
SerialPort sp = new SerialPort("COM11", 57600);

try
{
    sp.Open();

    Stopwatch timer = new Stopwatch();
    timer.Start();
    while (timer.Elapsed.TotalSeconds < 10)
    {
        // do something
    }
    timer.Stop();

    //byte b = (byte)sp.ReadByte();
    //char c = (char)sp.ReadChar();
    //string line = sp.ReadLine();
    string all = sp.ReadExisting();
    //string all2 = sp.ReadExisting();


    //Console.WriteLine(b);
    //Console.WriteLine(c);
    //Console.WriteLine(line);
    //Console.WriteLine(all);
    Console.WriteLine(all);

    sp.Close();

}
```

Suggestions?

Comment: Do not read synchronously is it not reliable on windows.  I have had issue for 40 years reading serial ports.  The only way of reliably reading is to use Async Method.

Comment: @jdweng any suggestions on how to properly do this different approach?